# Object instantiation error

Tags: java

I have written a piece of code as below.
that gives error instead of printing SUCCESS.

```
class A
{
    {
        new B();
    }

    static class B
    {
        {
            new A().new C();
        }
    }

    class C
    {
        {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        }
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new A();
    }
}
```

Please help me where it fails.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: An instance of A creates an instance of B: `new B();` and an instance of B creates an instance of A: `new A().new C();`

Comment: Is this even a thing? new A().new C(); and why do you even need that in the first place just do new C();

Comment: @Daedric `C` is an inner class of `A`, so it must have an enclosing instance of `A` in order to be instantiated.

Comment: @Eran Ahh thanks I see, didn't notice the nested class structure.

Comment: @SureshAtta I think the OP thought "If I am posting on *Stack Overflow* it means everybody will understand that the error is `StackOverflowError`"

Comment: @sudo Haha. You are 100% true in this context :D

Answer (score 4):

You got an infinite chain of constructor calls that starts with `new A();`, which
creates an instance of `A`, which creates an instance of `B` (due to `new B();` in the instance initializer block of class `A`), which creates another instance of `A` (due to `new A().new C();` in the instance initializer block of class `B`), which creates another instance of `B`, and so on...

This leads to `StackOverflowError`.

The instance of `C` is never created, which is why `System.out.println("SUCCESS");` is never executed.